I have a Blazor ASP.NET Core 8.0 Routing Error
I'm at a loss here when it comes what appears to be a routing error in my Blazor ASP.NET Core 8.0 application. It's loading the main screen which is at page /. There is another file called _Host.cshtml that also has page /, but when I remove that, I get an error:

stdout: fail:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
Matches:
Blazor static files
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(Span1 candidateState)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, Span1 candidateState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, Span`1 candidateState)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.SelectAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidateSet)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.g__AwaitMatch|10_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

I have looked at all my routes and I cannot find two that are the same. I'll keep looking since I have a LOT of razor files to check, but could there be another angle I could be looking at to solve this problem or is it really just two of my razor files have the same route?

Without any other information on the configuration or type of your application, keep looking.

I thought ASP.NET Core Blazor is enough informatoin for type and configuration. It a web application configured with Blazor and ASP.NET. Am I missing or wrong about that assumption? Am I right to assume this error means I have two razor files that have the same routing path? Or could this error mean something else. I'm more interested in the error's meaning.

Render Mode? Interactivity location?  The error looks like it is happening during pre-rendering.  Did you upgrade an older project.  A Net8 Blazor project doesn't normally have a _ Host file.

In blazor .net 8, we have blazor web app and blazor wsam, in blazor web app, we have server side rendered mode/client side render mode/auto mode. But none of these have _Host.cshtml file. So that I'm afraid you are using a project which is upgraded from a lower version .net core. I test in my .net 7 blazor server app and I comment @page "/", I didn't get your error but another error. Could you please let us know what you are concerning now? Why you are trying to delete it?

I did update the project. From net 6 to net 8. I did it through visual studio

could there be another angle I could be looking at to solve this problem or is it really just two of my razor files have the same route --> could you please help confirm whether your will faced the same error if you didn't delete @page "/" in _Host.cshtml? By the way, I think we'd better to check the migration guidance from blazor server to blazor web app because in .net 8 blazor, we shouldn't have _Host.cshtml file.

In .Net 6 blazor server we have _Host.cshtml which doesn't exist in .Net 8 blazor web app(.net 8 doesn't have blazor server, but have blazor web app instead). We can see from the migration guidance that we need to remove _Host.cshtml.

Move the content in the _Host page (Pages/_Host.cshtml) to the empty
App.razor file. Proceed to make the following changes to the App
component.

In blazor server, we have app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); in Program.cs so that when a request to visit the root path, it comes to _Host which configures the initial setup and routing for the server-side aspect of the Blazor application. While the @page "/" in Index.raozr defines the content to be displayed for the root URL (/) within the client-side Blazor application, which play the role somewhat like the client-side route path. Just like in normal client-side app uses html file name to work as the route.
In my blazor server .net 6 application when I comment @page "/" in _Host.cshtml, I will get error like below which is different than yours.

I'm afraid that before we trying to find the Routing definition for causing AmbiguousMatchException, we could firstly check the migration guidance and check whether we missed any steps or not. In my test, if I just not deleting the _Host.cshtml, it won't cause your exception too.

Someone mentioned they were confused in seeing the _Host.cshtml. I'm surprised the update didn't remove it. I updated the project using the Visual Studio update. I'm sure this is the issue. I'm trying two angles to this problem: create a blazor web app through VS with authentication already installed and just integrate my old project into this, or integrate web authentication into my already existing project.

Keep the @page "/" directive in _host.cshtml. It is supposed to be there.
